# Kotlin: Recycler View Choppy

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, kotlin

My adapter is applying images correctly to the RecyclerView and scrolls properly... until I add a large amount of items.  It then becomes fairly choppy and I know it's an issue with my approach.  See the code below:

```
class FragmentMenuViewAdapter(private val menuItems: ArrayList<MenuItemModel>, private val clickListener: (MenuItemModel) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<FragmentMenuViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {

        val policy = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_list_items, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return menuItems.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {

        var menuItemIconURI = RouteManager.mAppModel?.resourcesURL + menuItems[position].icon

        menuItemIconURI = menuItemIconURI.replace("\$platform", "iOS")
        menuItemIconURI = menuItemIconURI.replace("\$scale", "@3x")

        val inputStream = URL(menuItemIconURI).openStream()
        holder.view.menuButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream))
        holder.bind(menuItems[position], clickListener)
    }

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        fun bind(menuItem: MenuItemModel, clickListener: (MenuItemModel) -> Unit) {
            view.setOnClickListener{clickListener(menuItem)}
        }
    }
}
```

The image(s) are being set via URL links.  I have it working, but I suspect I'm making a novice mistake somewhere, or am simply taking the wrong approach.  Any advice on how to adjust my code would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from decoding bitmap image in main thread. Try to use `Glide` instead. It helps us to load images asynchronously when needed. For example if you want to scroll the `RecyclerView` fast, it doesn't need to decode and show all images. In addition it has a caching mechanism to make this process smoother.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
}
```

**FragmentMenuViewAdapter.kt**

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {

    var menuItemIconURI = RouteManager.mAppModel?.resourcesURL + menuItems[position].icon

    menuItemIconURI = menuItemIconURI.replace("\$platform", "iOS")
    menuItemIconURI = menuItemIconURI.replace("\$scale", "@3x")

    Glide.with(holder.view.menuButton.context)
        .load(menuItemIconURI)
        .into(holder.view.menuButton)

    holder.bind(menuItems[position], clickListener)
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I will give this a shot.  Will report back; thanks!

Comment: Excellent response and I highly appreciate it.  This worked absolutely perfectly.  Well done!